# function cannot be overloaded error c++

Tags: c++

I'm learning composition by making a connect 4 game that has a column class within a board class. I have spent forever trying to figure out these overloading errors:

```
g++ -g -c C4Board.cpp -o C4Board.o
C4Board.cpp:11:1: error: ‘C4Board::C4Board()’ cannot be overloaded
 C4Board(){
 ^
In file included from C4Board.cpp:9:0:
C4Board.h:7:5: error: with ‘C4Board::C4Board()’
     C4Board();
     ^
C4Board.cpp:20:1: error: ‘C4Board::~C4Board()’ cannot be overloaded
 ~C4Board(){}
 ^
In file included from C4Board.cpp:9:0:
C4Board.h:9:5: error: with ‘C4Board::~C4Board()’
     ~C4Board();
     ^
C4Board.cpp:20:12: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
 ~C4Board(){}
            ^
```

Here are my constructors:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "C4Col.h"
#include "C4Board.h"

C4Board(){
  numCol = 7;
}

C4Board(int columns){
  numCol = columns;
}

~C4Board(){}
```

I got rid of the `C4Board::` before the constructors because it gave me this error in addition to the overloading errors:

```
    error: extra qualification ‘C4Board::’ on member ‘C4Board’ [-fpermissive]
 C4Board::C4Board(){
 ^
```

Here is my .h file, although I don't believe it's the problem:

```
class C4Board{
  public:
    C4Board();
    C4Board(int);
    ~C4Board();
    void display();
    void play();
  private:
    int numCol;
    C4Col Board[7];
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `I got rid of the C4Board:: before the constructors ` you need to have it in the .cpp

Comment: Now you have edited your question and changed the .h file. It is still wrong (missing a semicolon at the end), but _have you tested that your change didn't fix the errors that you are asking about_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compiler is recognizing functions as different, you have to specify that these are the definitions of your class methods...

```
C4Board::C4Board(){
  numCol = 7;
}

C4Board::C4Board(int columns){
  numCol = columns;
}
C4Board::~C4Board(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

If that really is your .h file, it's missing a final `}`. That can give these symptoms.

Remember that the `#include` can be seen as putting the entire text of the .h file into the .cpp file. A missing final `}` results in your function definitions from the .cpp file being *inside* the class definition from the .h file.